# How to increment by constant number while summing numbers in Labview?

Tags: labview

I just started learning Labview today, and have been doing a lot of online searching and looking at example code. However, I still find myself stuck on some simple concepts.

Currently I'm trying to write a simple code that sums up all the numbers less than or equal to `N` that are multiples of both 3 and 5. Here is an image of what I have right now. I feel like it's close, but that I'm missing a key aspect to make the loop add up all the numbers that pass this criteria (instead of just the last one).

[image]

To try to walk you through it -- I have a for loop, and I start by specifying some number `N` (or rather N+1) that I went to iterate to. I also set `i` to equal 5, so that I start iterating through with the number 5 (I think) and continue in multiples of 5. Then, I divide the input number by 3, and check if the remainder is equal to 0 or not. If it is, then it's a multiple of 3 as well, so a boolean gets set to True and I add this number to my final sum (+0, because I didn't know what else to put there). If it's not, I just add 0. The final sum is then calculated.

If I start with N=16 in the top left, my "final sum" indicator says 15, which is correct because 15 is the only number from 5-15 that is a multiple of both 3 and 5. However, if I try 1001 for example, my "final sum" indicator says 0. So I think it is only performing these checks and sums for the last number in the loop -- or all the previous results are getting overwritten. I'm not sure how to fix this though (I tried a shift register but then deleted it because I think that would bring my final sum to the input of the new loop, which isn't what I want). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: While you're at this stage of learning, I strongly suggest running your code with execution highlighting turned on (the lightbulb icon in the toolbar). That will help you understand what data is flowing from where to where. When you reach the point that execution highlighting is too slow, learn to use probes and breakpoints as those are also essential tools for debugging LabVIEW code and/or learning how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that the output tunnel from your for loop is set to "Last Value," which means what's written into Final Sum is just what's on that wire the final time. Another option is to make that tunnel Indexing. You have a wire doing that, but then you're performing no operation on it. If you sum the array elements of that auto-generated array (that's what indexing does), then you'll get the output you're looking for.

Also, you can't write to i; it just gives you the current index of the for loop.

Given the simplicity of the execution involved, I wouldn't worry about executing steps that are not needed, so you don't need to worry about incrementing by anything other than 1. Which is good, because in LabVIEW, For loops always increment by one.

But if this calculation was more costly, there would be ways around that, like iterating fewer times and scaling the index before using it in calculations.

Here is a minor modification of what you've done, but that should work, which I just fixed based on nekomatic's comment:

[image: Code Snippet]

And here is code that would accomplish the same, but with fewer executions:

[image: Code Snippet 2]

Comment: This will sum all the numbers **less than** `N` that are multiples of 3. The loop index terminal starts counting from 0 and the loop runs N times.

Comment: Good catch - need to play with the iterations to make it less than _or equal to_. I also missed the detail in the questioner's post about the number also needing to be divisible by 5, and just inferred the divisible by three bit from the code screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload here VI, or VI snippet (not screenshot). Because now, with all that wires going from right to left, it is difficult to do something... 
And regarding issue - final sum of course is empty, b/c you do not add previous results. Store it to shift register, and add values to it if needed.